# vb.net ErrorProvider1 - setting Autovalidate?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

how do I set the Autovalidate? I tried with the line bellow but this is wrong way, I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
So what is the right way of setting this? 
thanks

```
ErrorProvider1.ContainerControl.AutoValidate = Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange
```

Comment: no, this gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For a form, add this to the Form_Load event:

```
Me.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable
```

This will override all the controls that have CausesValidation set to True and force you to use ValidateChildren() on a button click event.

Does that help? Or are you looking for into on ErrorProviders?